# FMDataBase - Where i should store the database File ?

Tags: xcode, macos

I use FMDatabase to deal more easier with SQLite dataBase, but i have a little problem: I don't want to create database file after installing app, because i want to deliver an preloaded data. 
If i copy my database file in Build Phase , all files stored in that paths are read only so when I try to insert something in dataBase, I get an error:  Error inserting batch: attempt to write a readonly database.

So my Question is : Where should I store/copy that file to be able to update database ? and second: May I copy file via Build Phases ?

[image: Copy files]

Answer (score 1):

In `DocumentDirectory` you can read/write your data. But you need to copy your database to this directory before use.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) you can find comprehensive information about directory structure in iOS file system.

Comment: I think I will just copy the file with NSFileManager in Aplication Support, at start of application.